# Cannot calculate difference between two dates

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to calculate the difference in days between two date columns (date1 and date2). I imported a data set from csv file and the date format for date1 and date2 look as following:

```
8/22/18 19:05
```

First I tried to merely calculate the difference

```
data_test$dif <- data_test$date2 - data_test$date1
```

This led to an error **"non-numeric argument to binary operator"**

Then I thought to transform the variables into the as.Date format

```
data_test$date <- as.Date(data_test$date1)
```

But I get the error: **"character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"**

After spending various hours reading other posts I also tried unsucessfully

```
library(lubridate)
data_test$date <- ymd_hm(data_test$date1)
```

Receiving the error **"All formats failed to parse. No formats found. "**

Can you please help me finding the solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Based on what you imported you should use `mdy_hm()`.

Comment: Using base R you could also do `as.POSIXct(d,format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`, or `as.Date(d,format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")` if the time component is not important.

Comment: @AntoniosK Thank you. That works. How would I then calculate the difference in days? E.g. currently when subtracting "2018-08-24  - 2018-08-20 14:06:00" I get 294840 instead of 4 days

Comment: @Neicooo the `difftime` result is in seconds.

Comment: Not sure what function you use to calculate the difference, but here's an example: `mdy_hm("8/26/18 19:05") - mdy_hm("8/22/18 19:05")`, or `difftime(mdy_hm("8/26/18 19:05"), mdy_hm("8/22/18 19:05"), units = "days")`